# ApplicationController layout is being overriden by inherited classes? Ruby on Rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, view, ruby-on-rails-2, controllers

I am developing a Rails 2 application and only have the need for one layout template for my multiple controllers so I created one application.html.erb to be used and put

```
layout 'application'
```

into my ApplicationController (which all the controllers are definitely inheriting from) but the controllers still render their default layouts upon running the application.

I have seen from [this page](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Layout/ClassMethods/layout) that inserting the layout method into my ApplicationController is all that is needed to make a default layout, and it seems to be overridden by the inherited controllers. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Are there other files in your app/views/layouts? Sometimes I've seen rails 2 scaffolding create a products.html.erb there. If so, remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are other layout view files they will be used over the default. You need to either remove the other layout files (they will have the same name as a controller), or define  `layout 'application'` in every controller that you want to use it.

Comment: Wow. I did not see this detail in any documentation I looked up. Thanks for the help.